# Layer doesn't turn back on after clicking in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have the following code. I have setup a default function of turning the showing all my layers and on click the layers disappear. But they don't turn back on when I click on them.
So what have I done wrong here?

```
 <input type="checkbox" onClick="vector_summer.setVisible(false);"  id="ch_summer" name="summer" checked>Summer 
 <input type="checkbox" onClick="vector_winter.setVisible(false);"  id="ch_winter" name="winter" checked>Winter 
 <input type="checkbox" onClick="vector_relay_route.setVisible(false);"  id="ch_SLC2002" name="SLC2002" checked>Salt Lake City 2002
 <input type="checkbox" onClick="slc_2002_torch.setVisible(false);"  id="ch_none" name="none" checked>Torch
```

Then this is how I am calling the layers later on:

`var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, us_states_vec, slc_2002_torch, vector_summer,
           vector_winter,vector_relay_route],
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([34.59, 31.59], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 2
  })
});
vector_summer.setVisible(true);
vector_winter.setVisible(true);
vector_relay_route.setVisible(true);
us_states_vec.setVisible(true);
slc_2002_torch.setVisible(true);`

What do I do so that the layers get turned back after I uncheck them?

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers provide a way to bind an html element to a layer property :

`var visible = new ol.dom.Input(document.getElementById('visible'));
visible.bindTo('checked', layer, 'visible');`

[See this in action in this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/bind-input.html)

Comment: I forgot about that. If you are just dealing with pure JavaScript, this is probably the best way to go.

Comment: This is I think the best way.  I am trying to dynamically add checkboxes to a page after loading new layers, and bind them like this, however I am having a problem with the bindings on Vector layers, in case you run into something similar 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240516/openlayers-3-binding-a-checkbox-to-a-vector-layer-for-visibility/29296759#29296759

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a variable to pass to the setVisible function in your onclick instead of hard coding it. You can initialize it when the page loads. Then you would simply just do this `onClick="vector_summer.setVisible(!summerVisible); summerVisible = !summerVisible;"` .

If you are using angular you could hook up the model of the variable to the checkbox and that would make things a bit easier. It would also be a bit cleaner to pull the onClick into a javascript function instead, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it could be like this:

```
<section id="map"></section>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLayer(this)" name="osm" checked>OSM</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLayer(this)" name="mapquest" checked>MapQuest</input>

<!-- javascript code -->
<script>    
var map = new ol.Map({
    'layers': [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            style: 'Road',
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'}),
            name: 'mapquest'
        }), 
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            name: 'osm'
        })
     ],
    'renderer': 'canvas',
    'target': 'map',
    'view': new ol.View({
        'projection': 'EPSG:3857',
        'center': [1531627.8847864927, 6632124.286850829],
        'zoom': 4
    })
});

var toggleLayer = function(inputEl){
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
        if (layer.get('name') === inputEl.name)
            layer.setVisible(inputEl.checked);
    });
};
</script>
```

Important is, that in this examlple the checkbox should have the same name as the layers. Hope it helps.